# changing the Pixel Filtering per render pass

Tags: rendering

Is it possible to change the Blackman Harris filter settings per pass. 
I found the script commands in the manual. Is there a custom node in compositing that I could run the renderlayer through that I could enter new values?

Comment: ok, I figured out a more straight forward solution. Duplicate the scene and render that out as its own pass.

Comment: Still can't figure it out. When I go to render multiple scenes it ignores all but the master scene render settings.

Comment: When I duplicate the scene I can render with custom render settings on the second scene.  If you're using the compositor, are you being sure to select the `Render Layer` from the new scene?